Pancake swap error while selling token with tax rate ( execution reverted: Pancake: K )
I got stucked at point, where i am selling tokens with tax rate on BSC chain.
I am working on crypto bot, and created it using ether.js and node.js. I am using Pancake swap for swapping tokens on BSC chain. Where i am stucked at point, where i am trying to sell tokens. It is working well for tokens without sale tax ( like :  PEPE), but on the another hand, tokens having sale tax, like Yoshi and other having problem while selling them, as I am unable to sell and getting error as.enter image description here
This is my code, regarding above logic.
//Sell Tokens or Convert to BNB
exports.processSell = async (ctx, tokenAddress, percentage, provider) => {
    try {
        const chat = ctx.chat.id;
        await connectToDb();
        const wallet = await walletSchema.findOne({ chat });

        // Validate amount percentage
        const parsedAmountPercentage = parseInt(percentage);
        if (isNaN(parsedAmountPercentage) || parsedAmountPercentage < 10 || parsedAmountPercentage > 100) {
            ctx.reply("Invalid amount percentage. Please enter a number between 10 and 100.", Markup.inlineKeyboard([
                [{ text: "Enter Again", callback_data: `/enter_percentage ${tokenAddress}` },
                { text: "Cancel Buy", callback_data: '/close' }
                ]
            ]).resize());
            return;
        }

        // Convert amount percentage to actual amount based on token balance
        const walletResponse = await Moralis.EvmApi.wallets.getWalletTokenBalancesPrice({ address: wallet.walletId, chain: EvmChain.BSC });
        const walletData = walletResponse.toJSON().result;
        const token = walletData.find(token => token.token_address.toLowerCase() === tokenAddress.toLowerCase());
        const slippage = wallet.sellSlip || 5;

        if (!token) {
            ctx.reply("Token not found in your wallet.");
            return;
        }
        if (token.usd_value < 4.5) {
            ctx.reply('You should have $4.5 usd value of tokens to swap them.');
            return;
        }

        const tokenBalance = token.balance_formatted;
        let amount = (parsedAmountPercentage / 105) * tokenBalance;

        console.log("Token amount", amount);

        let tokenAmtSlippage = amount * (1 - slippage / 100);
        tokenAmtSlippage = tokenAmtSlippage.toFixed(0); // Convert to string to append .01 or .99
        tokenAmtSlippage = parseFloat(tokenAmtSlippage + (Math.random() > 0.5 ? '.99' : '.01'));

        console.log("Token slippage amount", tokenAmtSlippage);
        // Check if user has sufficient token balance to sell
        if (amount > tokenBalance) {
            ctx.reply("Insufficient token balance.");
            return;
        }

        // Proceed with swapping tokens back to BNB
        const privateKey = await wallet.decryptKey();
        const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

        // Approve Router Contract to spend tokens
        const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, TOKEN_BSC_ABI, signer);
        const routerAddress = PANCAKE_ROUTER;
        const routerAbi = TOKEN_BSC_ABI;
        const router = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerAbi, signer);

        const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20; // 20 minutes from now
        const path = [tokenAddress, '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c']; // Swap token to BNB

        const amountOutMin = 0; // Minimum amount of BNB to receive

        // Approve tokens for spending by router
        const amountWei = ethers.parseUnits(tokenAmtSlippage.toString(), 'ether');

        // Approve tokens for spending by router
        const approvalTx = await tokenContract.approve(routerAddress, amountWei);
        await approvalTx.wait();
        // Execute the swap
        const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForETH(
            amountWei,
            amountOutMin,
            path,
            signer.address,
            deadline,
        );

        // Wait for transaction to be mined
        const receipt = await tx.wait();

        ctx.reply(`Transaction Successfull! You swapped ${amount.toFixed(4)} tokens to BNB.`);


    } catch (error) {
        ctx.reply(`Transaction reverted due to gas fees, please select more amount of tokens or set slippage accordingly.`)
        console.log('Error', error)
    }
}

Where as this is my abi for selling token via pancake, swapping back to BNB.
const TOKEN_BSC_ABI = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "WETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountInMax",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];

// Connect to BSC network
const PANCAKE_ROUTER = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E";

Also, I have tried fixing it with setting slippage to 25%.
I have already checked the documentation of pancake swap and implemented the same.
Please help me fixing this error.
I just want to allow users to sell tokens having sales tax.
